# Refresh/Reload UITableView on every callback

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5

In my iOS5 application, I have UITableView that would display cells based on NSString values stored in progressLabelArray. I have registered a call back from my lower layers and I receive them in a C function from where I manage to call the UI update method through a reference to self.

```
    static void callback_handler(int nCode) {
        [refToSelf updateProgressView:nCode];
    }


    -(void) updateProgressView:(int32_t) nCode
    {
        NSString *status = nil;
        status = [self progressUpdateToString:nCode];
        [self.progressLabelArray    insertObject:status atIndex:0];
        [self.progressTableView reloadData];
        [self.progressTableView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
```

I guess, since the callbacks are coming on the same (UI thread), performSelectorOnMainThread may not be required.

My problem is that the table view only gets refreshed when the entire operation is complete, showing the last call back values. Is there a way by which I can force the UI to refresh after every callback? The callbacks coming might be relatively fast.

Comment: if the call back are coming too fast then how would you observe the change in the data i.e. why only the last change is visible

Comment: Firstly they are not too fast to get unnoticed and then when I debug and put a break after various callbacks, I just see the initial values on the View.

Comment: Still not able to resolve the issue. Please my dear iOS friends - Help!!!

Comment: send me your code at rathore619@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by running the progress code in a separate thread. The callbacks come on a seprate thread and there I update my main thread (UI thread). I guess the UI thread was not getting any cycles to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Put your

> tableView.reloadData()

call in the following block and your tableview will refresh without any issue and without refreshing the scroller like in realtime apps.

For swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async()
{
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

For Objective C:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Background work
    [tableView reloadData];

});
```